# Bluetooth+arduino and android authentication

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I have a device. I use microcontroller arduino. I have connected my device with my android application via bluetooth. And I want to do that only my application can connect to my device. What is the best way to do this authentification? Can I do this with bluetooth's special AT commands? If yes how? Or must I  send some key to the arduino from the application and check it?

Answer (score 0):

By defaukt bluetooth adapters accept all connections (no binding), so you have tobcheck if this is the right device explicitly. You can store data persistently in eeprom on microcontroller, where you should keep your app key. When new phone try to connect to your device you should check if device passed that key and if not, do nothing in response.